# 1:1 Relationship, Is this a good idea?

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database, ms-access-2013, database-management

I have a database that has 5 1:1 relationships. I have a table called SoftwareVersion. Each SoftwareVersion has 5 phases of certification. The PhaseStatus names are the same for all 5 phases. I could not enforce referential integrity with one PhaseStatus table and a Ph0Status, Ph1Status, etc, field in the SoftwareVersion table. So I built 5 join tables. Now I have 5 1:1 Relationships. Every SoftwareVersion has multiple phases that have a status, but each software version only has one Phase 0 status. Is this a good example of a legitimate 1:1 relationship or is there a better way to build this?

Answer (score 0):

> Every SoftwareVersion has multiple phases that have a status, but each software version only has one Phase 0 status.

I think you mean every SoftwareVersion has many phases, and each phase has one or more possible statuses at a time.

If so, from what I see you need only two tables.  You need a PhaseStatus table of all allowable combinations of {phase,status}.  Use a FK reference to that table as a constraint to make sure a SofwareVersion in any given phase has a valid status.  You might also want tables that enumerate the domains of phases and  statuses, in case they have other interesting properties, such as descriptions or perhaps time constraints.

Comment: So the only issue I have with this is that if I need to ad a new phase status, rather than add one record to the phase status table I would then need to add 5 records with duplicate information.

Comment: Similar, but not "duplicate".  A new Phase has its own set of valid statuses that need to be defined.  Those rows are different from all other rows; they're not duplicates.  Also not a big deal, because how often will you add a phase, and how many statuses could it have?  Probably a couple of SQL statements and you're done.  If you wanted to, though -- if you want to *require* that two phases allow exactly the same set of statuses -- you could create a StatusGroup table keyed by a StatusGroupId, and use that as a FK in a Phases table instead of a single PhaseStatus table.